# Trying to build an algorithm for determining Big $\mathcal O$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, asymptotics

By the definition of Big $\mathcal O$ we have :

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $(N \lor R) \to R.$
We say that $f(x)$ is in $\mathcal O(g(x))$ iff there are constants $C$, $k$ such that

$$f(x) \leq Cg(x) , \,\, \forall x > k$$

Attempt:

By assuming that $g(x)\ne 0,\,\, \forall x \in R$ , we can divide with $g(x)$ both sides and obtain :

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq C, \space \space \forall x > k$$

From here we can find $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ on both sides and we have that:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \lim_{x\to \infty} C ,\,\, \forall x > k,$$

which is same as :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq  C, \,\,\forall x > k$$

From here , if the limit exists then we can conclude that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ , because we have found constant $C$ and we can easily find constant $k$.

If the limit does not exist, then we can tell that $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ , and we are unable to find constant $C$ such that the inequality will be true  $\forall x > k$.

My question is , is this method alright or am I making mistake somewhere ?

Comment: It is possible that $\lim f/g$ does not exist but still $f = O(g)$.

Comment: How to approach such cases , any ideas ?

Comment: There is no universal trick to determine asymptotics. Limits are very useful, but they cannot handle every case. What you really want is $\limsup$: $$|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)| \quad \forall x > k \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \limsup_{x \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right\rvert < \infty.$$ But this is just a restatement of the big-O property---it doesn't really make the determination of the asymptotics any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your argumentation looks valid. I'm not sure if you are aware that this is known, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) and [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:O_Notation/Big-O_Notation#Real_Analysis) and for a most rigorous formal proof e.g. in Mizar look [here](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/asympt_0.html#K6), [here](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/asympt_0.html#E27) and [here](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/asympt_0.html#T16).